# Cannot connect to sql server after recreating Windows admin account on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, sql-server-2012

I installed SQL Server 2012 on my new Windows 8 installation. The installation went well but the next day I had problems with my local Windows account (I originally added this account to the local Administrators group).

For some reason, my Windows account was using the wrong profile. I ended up fixing that problem by recreating a new Windows account (with the same credentials and also added it to the local Administrators account as before).

But now when I log in with this Windows account, I cannot connect to my local SQL Server. I get a Login Failed error. I cannot log in either using the sa account. It looks like I'm locked out of my local SQL Server.

Can anyone help steer me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your new Windows account has a different [SID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403629%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) than the old account did.  When a logon attempt is made, all SQL really cares about is the SID.  New SID?  Different user.

There's a way to log in to SQL in single-user mode as a sysadmin, provided you at least have a Windows account that is in the local admins group (so you should be good to go there).  You'll have to start it up in [single-user mode](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx) first.  From the link above:

> Starting SQL Server in single-user mode enables any member of the
>   computer's local Administrators group to connect to the instance of
>   SQL Server as a member of the sysadmin fixed server role.

Once you've done this, you're able to create or alter logins as you see fit, then restart SQL normally.

Here's a [walkthrough on the whole process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx).